# Calculating percentage with Pymongo project and devide returns None

Tags: python, project, aggregation-framework, pymongo

I'm currrently learning Python - so this might be a quite easy question for you.
However, I did not find a solution while browsing, so I hope to find help here ;)

I want to get the percentage of the amount of rows that have Condition>=5.

- The first query successfully returns the # of rows matching the condition (e.g. 400)
- The second one successfully returns the total (e.g. 2000).
- The third one ($project) always Returns "None"instead of 0.2 as expected

I would really appreciate any help. 
Thanks!

```
def get_percentage(collection):

    coll = collection.aggregate([
        #get No of rows with Condition>=5
        {"$match": { "Condition": {"$gte":5} }},
        {"$group": {"_id": 0, "count": {"$sum":1}}}
        ,
        #get total No of rows
        {"$group": {"_id": 0, "total": {"$sum":1}}}
        ,
        #get percentage: count/total
        {"$project" : {"percentage" : {"$divide" : ["$count","$total"]}}}
    ])

    for dot in coll:
        print(dot['percentage'])
        percentage = dot['percentage']
    return percentage
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [$cond](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/cond/) to count rows which `Condition >= 5`. Below statement is wrote in javascript. You need to quote keys in python.

```
collection.aggregate([{
    $project: {count: {$cond: {if: {$gte: ['$Condition', 5]}, then: 1, else: 0}}}
}, {
    $group: {_id: 0, count: {$sum: '$count'}, total: {$sum: 1}}
}, {
    $project: {"percentage" : {"$divide" : ["$count","$total"]}}
}])
```

Comment: that works ! 
thank you so much :) 

However, I still do not understand the "why" - why did my code not return a result?

Comment: @Paley I suggest that you start with printing output of each step.